# Shading over plot with funcanimation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to shade over a map to show "explored regions" of the dot as it moves around using FuncAnimation. This is the code I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import random
import scipy.stats as stats

map_x = 100
map_y = 100
fig = plt.figure(0)
plt.figure(0)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,3), (0,0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,3), (0,2), colspan=1)
ax1.set_xlim([0, map_x])
ax1.set_ylim([0, map_y])
ax2.set_xlim([0, map_x])
ax2.set_ylim([0, map_y])
agent = plt.Circle((50, 1), 2, fc='r')
agent2 = plt.Circle((50, 1), 2, fc='r')
agents = [agent, agent2]
ax1.add_patch(agent)
ax2.add_patch(agent2)

def animate(i):
    x, y = agent.center
    x = x+.1
    y = y+.1
    agent.center = (x, y)
    agent2.center = (x, y)
    return agent,

def fillMap(x, y):
    circle=plt.Circle((x,y), 4, fc='b')
    ax2.add_patch(circle)

def animate2(i):
    x, y = agent2.center
    x = x+.1
    y = y+.1
    agent2.center = (x, y)
    fillMap(x, y)
    return agent2,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
anim2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate2, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

However, it only goes into fillMap once, and only draws the blue filled in circle once, instead of everywhere where the red dot goes in the smaller subplot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the circle you added to persist on the screen you probably shouldn't use blitting. Not using blitting makes the animation slower, but it may be enough to draw a new blue circle every 20th step or so.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

map_x = 100
map_y = 100
fig = plt.figure(0)
plt.figure(0)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,3), (0,0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,3), (0,2), colspan=1)
ax1.set_xlim([0, map_x])
ax1.set_ylim([0, map_y])
ax2.set_xlim([0, map_x])
ax2.set_ylim([0, map_y])
agent = plt.Circle((50, 1), 2, fc='r')
agent2 = plt.Circle((50, 1), 2, fc='r')
agents = [agent, agent2]
ax1.add_patch(agent)
ax2.add_patch(agent2)


def fillMap(x, y):
    circle=plt.Circle((x,y), 4, fc='b')
    ax2.add_patch(circle)

def animate2(i):
    x, y = agent.center
    x = x+.1
    y = y+.1
    agent.center = (x, y)
    x, y = agent2.center
    x = x+.1
    y = y+.1
    agent2.center = (x, y)
    if i%20==0:
        circle = fillMap(x, y)


anim2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate2, frames=200, interval=20, blit=False)

plt.show()
```

In case you want to use blitting, consider using a line to mark the region where the circle has been.

```
line, =ax2.plot([],[], lw=3, color="b")
xl = []; yl=[]
def fillMap(x, y):
    xl.append(x); yl.append(y)
    line.set_data(xl,yl)
    return line

def animate2(i):
    x, y = agent.center
    x = x+.1
    y = y+.1
    agent.center = (x, y)
    x, y = agent2.center
    x = x+.1
    y = y+.1
    agent2.center = (x, y)
    if i%20==0:
        fillMap(x, y)
    return agent, agent2, line

anim2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate2, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
```